# How to use ffplay to play a rtp stream without sdp?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there any command line options that I can use to tell `ffplay` the video stream format of the RTP stream?

With a simple `SDP` file like bellow, I can play the stream very well.

```
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
m=video 9170 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```